# What is the name of this power connector?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

It is mainly found on electric bikes and scooters in order to recharge batteries.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would need an extension cord. It is hard to find without the name.

Comment: Try google image search **not by words** but by your own picture as request ; it answers many many quit similar connectors,  So this one looks like N3F & XLR familly.

Comment: @francoisP: it doesn't look like an XLR to me.

Comment: @francoisP That's definitely not XLR. It's not N3F either, since that has a rectangular cutout in the shell; it's not plain circular like this. Besides, N3F seems to be used almost exclusively for camera shutter remotes, and I wouldn't expect it to carry much power at all. It's quite a lot smaller than this one, too.

Comment: GX16 by the look of it. Bit smaller than an XLR, rated up to 10A.

Answer (score 8):

It is a GX connector, commonly known as an "aviation connector". It is also called "HS" by Hirose and WB by Weipu.

My [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&o=standard_metal_circular_conn&f=aviation_gx_circular_conn&fl=000000000000000000000000000-140-%7C3%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) lists 20 possible matches:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- *Industry standard* - GX12
- *Industry standard* - GX12 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX16
- *Industry standard* - GX16 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX20
- *Industry standard* - GX20 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX25
- *Industry standard* - GX25 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX30
- *Industry standard* - GX30 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX35
- *Industry standard* - GX35 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX40
- *Industry standard* - GX40 rev
- *Industry standard* - GX48
- *Industry standard* - GX48 rev
- Hirose - HS12
- Hirose - HS16
- Hirose - HS21
- Hirose - HS25

If you click on one of the items, it gives you sourcing information.

If you give us the diameter of the black part (in mm, please) I can narrow it down for you.

Comment: That connector shape and size is common to all electric bikes chargers where the batterry is rated for 48V or higher.

Comment: My aim is to add an external battery to the bike so I would need an edged extension cord.

Comment: Wat do you mean by "edged"?

Answer (score 4):

> I would need an extension cord. It is hard to find without the name.

You would have to purchase a *'GX16 3P Male/Female Head Aviation Socket Connector Electrical Cable - 2m'.*

[image]

You may also make your own using a *'GX16 3P Male / Female'* pair.

You would need to confirm that the current carrying capacity of the cable is adequate for your requirement.

Comment: I would need an edged extension cord. The aim is to add an external battery.

Comment: What's an edged extension cord?

Comment: An extension cord where one of it s connectors is edged.

Comment: @user2284570, it's been 2 days and you still haven't answered my question. What is the diameter of the black cylinder? I need it in order co complete the identification.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I don’t have the tooling to measure it. It’s just on an electric bike to the size is implied.

Comment: OK, then please take a picture next to a coin. I can then look up the diameter of the coin, and estimate the size. Or, next to a credit card.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the type fitted to the flying lead from the DC supply of my Yamaha mixing desk i.e. one of these: -

[image]

It's quite commonly used as far as I know so maybe buy a DC supply from [these people](https://gbr.grandado.com/products/mixing-console-mixer-power-supply-ac-adapter-15v-230ma-universal-4-pin-round-connector?variant=UHJvZHVjdFZhcmlhbnQ6NDM0NjY0OTA&gclid=CjwKCAjwk6-LBhBZEiwAOUUDp_GB1wlZjunR9FZYeBkvXNIJhqpLNDtFK8DVR3tFibSYxJUXRIZekhoCrvIQAvD_BwE) or from [these people](https://www.ubuy.com.tr/en/product/1E85UHOO-replacement-ac-adapter-power-supply-for-yamaha-mg10xu-10-channel-mixer) and cut the connector off.

Here's also the [user manual](https://shopwl.com/content/MG10%20Mixing%20Console%20-%20Manual.pdf) for the mixer - maybe there are more details in there about it.

Wow, my first hit and I found it [here](https://cpc.farnell.com/pro-signal/psg08608/socket-multipole-3p/dp/CN21152?mckv=s_dc%7Cpcrid%7C426684131039%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7CCN21152%7Cpgrid%7C100371158878%7Cptaid%7Cpla-1252988897517%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-CPC-SHOPPING&s_kwcid=AL!5616!3!426684131039!!!network%7D!1252988897517!&gclid=CjwKCAjwk6-LBhBZEiwAOUUDp7Ci2WgG5ZfJ2jvRaXh--CkSIbABbce9T_q-6X7naviO1drPhyewMRoC7o4QAvD_BwE) searching for "`3 pin connector with knurled lock nut`": -

[image]

Comment: I would need an edged extension cord. The aim is to add an external battery.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found plugs alone on may vendors sites the name of the plug is

3 PIN 16mm or 18mm GX16-3 Screw.

Comment: They aren t edged.