# 2-pin connector identification

Tags: identification, connector

What is the connector shown on the images below? I need to create some more cables with this connector on one side to connect to one of our devices, but unfortunately, I have no idea what type of connector this is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After being cut open:

[image]

As you can see, it is a 2-pin connector with a female thread on the inside. The metal housing is 16 mm long (scale is in cm), the inner black part of the connector is 6 mm in diameter. It has an alignment groove and two offset pin holes. The letter on its front appears to be a capital "G". The connector is used as part of a warning light system, and carries a few volts of DC voltage with almost no current.

Comment: Looks like it might be an "M" series connector, like an M8-2. [McMaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/m8-connectors/) might have it.  Will have to measure with a caliper to ensure sizes are correct.

Comment: Is that scale in cm or inches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name of this power connector?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590995/what-is-the-name-of-this-power-connector)

Comment: @rdtsc No, certainly not an IEC M8 connector. IEC M8 connectors [look very different](http://connectorbook.com/classes/round_conn/circular_conn//compimg/M5.jpg).

Comment: @DavideAndrea The scale is in cm

Comment: Do you have some more details on the warning light system that this connector is currently being used? Maybe that will have some details that we can use to search for

Comment: I'd search among the terms of M6 to M8 2 pin with some strange coding. Poke it open to see how the wires are attached. It will narrow down the search somewhat. Is it screws, crimp, IDC etc? Also why not just tear it down and replace with a standard 3 pin M8 from Phoenix.

Comment: @thisjt Unfortunately, the system is a custom-built system that was created over 10 years ago, so there's no information to get there I think (the people who built it are also all long-gone)

Comment: @Lundin I've cut it open to see how it looks inside (also in the hopes of finding some label identifying the connector, but no luck). As for replacing the connectors: Yeah, that might be a last backup-option... The issue is that there are 30 connectors or so on that device, and quite a few existing cables, all of which would need to be changed in that case

Comment: Well I've searched a lot, it does look like very much like a GX connector... I would guess it's some weird audio connector... I'd probably contact Amphenol or Hirose etc ask them if they have anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally identified the connector: It is a [M9 IP40, Female cable connector, Series 711](https://www.binder-connector.com/en/products/subminiature-circular-connectors/m9-ip40/female-cable-connector-3#99007210002) connector from binder:

[image]

What ultimately led me to this was a string of lucky coincidences, where I noticed the company logo in a product catalog, which I incorrectly identified at "G" before:

[image]

[image]

By now I have received the connectors, and they are indeed the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

It's a circular connector.

EDIT: It's not a GX connector. It has a mating diameter of 6 mm, so it's too small for a GX, which start at 12 mm.

EDIT 2: here is it in my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&o=propr_plastic_circ_conn&f=propr_plastic_threaded_circ_conn&s=M9%20IP40%20711), thanks to @ Lukas Lang

Comment: Thanks, that website looks extremely helpful! (Unfortunately, I did not find it during my quick googling before when I was looking for something like it). As I now note in the updated question, the scale is in cm. The black part is around 6mm in diameter. I took a quick look through the list of connectors, you have identified, but so far, most of them seemed too big

Comment: Yeah, I can't find anything with a 6 mm mating diameter that looks like that. Sorry. I removed my answer.

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help anyways! The connector style did seem very promising without knowing the size... (Maybe you could keep a link to your identification tool in your answer? While it did not have the correct connector this time, it's still a tool one should know about when looking to identify a connector. And the more "connector identification questions have a link to it, the more likely it is to be found by people looking for their connector)

Comment: > Maybe you could keep a link to your identification tool in your answer?  --- Here: http://connectorbook.com/identification.html